# Both sound good - how to pick?

Tags: sennheiser, interviews, adobe-audition, evaluation, ntg3

We've added a Rode NTG3 to our Sennheiser ew100G3 to capture voice in video interviews.

The both XLR into an H6.

Previously the setup was H6 with the X/Y attachment + the ew100G3.

Both recordings (Sennheiser + NTG3) sound great and can be used individually, BUT they also sound a tad different.

In Adobe Audition is there a way to evaluate/assess which recording is 'better'?

Not sure what criteria the quality of a recording should be assessed on.

Any input would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can measure distortion, especially at the edge of the useful envelope (ie see which one distorts first as you increase the volume of noises you want to record) or sensitivity (does one pick up quiet sounds better) but if they work equally well, then your best bet is to pick the one you like the sound of better.

This is likely to just be a slightly different frequency response curve, and there is no "better" when it comes to tonal preferences.

Comment: So tonal preference aside, you suggest to measure distortion by cranking it up? Is there a guide/reference to identify the useful envelope when it comes to human voice?

Comment: If you want flat response, you can look at the frequency response curves provided with each microphone. But really, you'll want the one that works best for you. I don't suggest cranking it up is a good way to measure distortion at all, it was just an example of one of the places where mics could be different.

Answer (score 0):

The 'better' of the good sounds is not going to be found inside a computer program (like Audition). If they both sound good but have been captured with different placements, then your problem is just about conforming to a placement style.

General advice:
Choose the lavalier for a more crisp, corporate but less naturalistic feel. If you can understand the dialogue as such, who cares about how natural it is? The product voice is promotional or for entertainment, both for which the sound source is isolated.

Or go with the boom mic / NTG3 to capture more of the environment, as you will surely here some audible reflections and reverb from the room that bring the viewer into the scene, but on a more down to earth level (not hyper-real or exaggerated). Provided that the mic is positioned correctly, the perspective of the camera is more likely to match, given that the mic is directional.

For video interviews I would be inclined to use the Lav mic and get accustomed to it and develop taste for it, but the choice is entirely up to you.

Comment: In light of all this, for talking head style explainer videos I'll keep using the Lav as suggested. For interviews I'll try the NTG3 a tad more. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming equivalent performance, "better" for you may mean higher sensitivity, lower self-noise, better directional response, more rugged, better resale value, lighter weight, cost/availability of accessories, etc. etc.